# Quick Regex question

Tags: regex

Can anybody guide me in the right direction...

I have some folder strucktures that I want to check for a trailing / slash, some of the folders don't have a trailing / and if it does not have a trailing
/ I need to add one

If I use this regex it works but it replace the last character of the folder name

```
    Folder/name/test
    folder/name/test1/
    folder/name/test2/
```

```
replace(/.$/ig,"/");
```

This regex replaces `Folder/name/tes[t]/`  but will take out the `t` and replace it with `/`

Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you made basically means this: take any character that is the last one in the string and replace it with /. What you need to do is to group the last character and then insert it again in the replacement, like this:

```
replace(/([^\/])$/ig,"$1/");
```

For more information see
http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: this would also add back the trailing slash if it exists, resulting in a double slash - equivalent to just appending a slash to everything.

Comment: Thanks a Million Schtibe - just learned something new again :-) It is cool - I thought that I might need to do it in two steps like adding a / to all and then replacing double // with one / again - Your answer is doing both for me in one step!!

Comment: You are right. A better way to do this would be
replace(/([^\/])$/ig,"$1/");
This replaces any trailing character that is not a slash

Comment: sorry, but this will append another `/` at the end of the line and could be done in a simpler way: `replace(/$/,"/");`.

I don't think this is completely correct in that sense

Comment: var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/\/\//ig,"/"); <<<< I have this in my code as well which takes a double // and makes it a single slash, so that is why I did not even notice the double slash appearing :-)

Comment: Edit your solution with the correct solution [^\/] instead of .

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
replace(/[^/]$/ig, "$0/")
```

Comment: replace(/[^/]$/ig, "$1/") - Think it would also have worked thanks Gumbo!

Comment: @Gerald Ferreira: `$0` is not a mistake, I used it on purpose.

Comment: Why Gumbo ? What is the reason

Comment: `$0` contains the matched string of the whole regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
replace(/(.)$/ig,"\1/");
```

or better

```
replace(/([^\\])$/ig,"\1/");
```

if \1 isn't a backreference in your language, then you'll have to figure that out, or tell us teh language.

Comment: I am using Javascript and ASP - replace(/([^\\\])$/ig,"\1/"); This solution replaces the last character with a block and then adds the slash after the block - like a unicode character that is missing

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the language it's difficult to post a correct answer and you can't use the code provided in a cut-and-paste fashion. Anyway I might go for this regex:

```
replace(/(.)\/*$/,"\1/");
```

This will append the trailing `/` **only** if it's not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which language this is for but this is how you would do it in Perl:

```
#! /local/bin/perl

my @data = <data>;
while (<DATA>)
{
    s#[^/]\n#/\n#m;
    print;
}

__DATA__
/foo/bar/
/baz/jazz
/baz/jazz
```

This then prints out the following:

```
/foo/bar/
/baz/jaz/
/baz/jazz/
```

The key to the regex is the "[^/]\n" This basically matches anything at the end next to to the newline. With your nomenclature, I would assume the syntax would be the following:

```
replace(/[^\/]\n/ig,"/");
```

Or if there is no newline use this:

```
replace(/[^\/]$/ig,"/");
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid a regular expressions in this case and do something easier like:

```
$path = rtrim($path, '/').'/';
```

EDIT:

Woops, assumed it was php...

Comment: The problem is that it is part of a bigger regex - I use to replace translated text

var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/ü|ù|ú/ig,"u");
var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/é|è/ig,"e");
var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/æ/ig,"ae");
var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/ø|ö|ò|ó/ig,"o");
var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/'/ig,"/");
var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/å|ä|à|á/ig,"a");
var strippeden3 = strippeden3.replace(/,/ig,"");